# In Tensorflow's C++ TensorShape API, what is the equivalent of Python's None?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

Suppose I have a tensor created with the Python API of Tensorflow, as follows,

```
x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, inputLen])
```

I would like to create a tensorflow::Tensor equivalent of that in C++, so that I can run a trained graph that takes x as the input. What should I do with the first dimension of the input shape, which in C++ is of type tensorflow::TensorShape?

If I do:

```
tensorflow::TensorShape inputShape;
inputShape.AddDim(0);
inputShape.AddDim(inputLen);
```

it doesn't seem to work, because num_elements becomes 0, which is not the value of inputLen that I expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: There is now a [`tensorflow::PartialTensorShape`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a5074383617a9947f248a0ddd56b94f9fb0f970b/tensorflow/core/framework/partial_tensor_shape.h) class that can represent shapes with unknown dimensions or an unknown rank. The value `-1` is used to represent an unknown value (i.e. what `None` represents in Python). It is used in the C++ shape inference code, and can be specified in a shape-typed attr or a `tf.TensorShape` proto.

---

**TL;DR:** There is no equivalent in C++ because the C++ part of TensorFlow only checks shapes at runtime, when they are fully defined; whereas the Python part checks shapes at graph-construction time, when they might not be fully defined.

There is no equivalent of [`tf.Dimension(None)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#Dimension) (i.e., an unknown dimension) in the C++ [`tensorflow::TensorShape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/cc/ClassTensorShape.html#class-tensorflow-tensorshape) class. This is because the (C++) `tensorflow::TensorShape` class describes the shape of a (C++) `tensorflow::Tensor`, which represents a **concrete** value for a tensor, and therefore must have a fully defined shape. The Python [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor) class represents a **symbolic** tensor—representing the output of an operation that has yet to be run—and so it can have a shape that is unknown in one or more dimensions.

If you are using the [C++ API](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/cc/ClassSession.html#class-tensorflow-session) to feed a placeholder, you should simply create a new [`tensorflow::Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/cc/ClassTensor.html#class-tensorflow-tensor) with a fully defined shape for each different value that you feed to the placeholder (in a `Session::Run()` call). Note however that the C++ API does not check shapes of placeholders, so you should manually ensure that the shape matches the expected shape for the placeholder.

If you are building a graph using the C++ API, and you want to *define* a placeholder with an unknown size in one or more dimensions, you should define a placeholder node with its `shape` attr set to `tensorflow::TensorShape({})`. Although this is equivalent to a scalar, for historical reasons this is treated as the shape being completely unconstrained.

Comment: Running something like tensorflow::Tensor X(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT, tensorflow::PartialTensorShape({-1, 32})) does not work. How do you use PartialTensorShape in conjunction with a tensor?

Comment: @Francesco did you find out how you use PartialTensorShape ?

Comment: The `tensorflow::Tensor` constructor requires a `TensorShape` object because it is responsible for allocating the memory for the tensor, and so all of the dimensions must be fully defined.